# Why after I press the "C" buttom in my calculator I can't use the number keys right after it, only the mouse click?

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to build a calculator, the problem is that after the "C" buttom is clicked I can't use the keyboard inputs, only the mouse. Before clicking on the "C" buttom the key inputs were working just fine.
This only occours right after the button is clicked, when the displayed text is still equal to 0.

It should probably be something very simple and stupid that I have messed up.
I'm using the windows form app in the Visual Studio to this solution.

Note: the only functions that this calculator have is the "c" (to set the text in the "printer" to 0) and the numbers.

```
private void mousePressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            if (printer.Text == "0") {
                printer.Text = button.Text;
            }
            else { printer.Text = printer.Text + button.Text; }
        }



        private void numberKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0) {
                if (printer.Text == "0") {
                    printer.Text = "0";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "0";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "1";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "1";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "2";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "2";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad3)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "3";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "3";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D4 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad4)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "4";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "4";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D5 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad5)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "5";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "5";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D6 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad6)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "6";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "6";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D7 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad7)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "7";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "7";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D8 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad8)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "8";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "8";
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D9 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                if (printer.Text == "0")
                {
                    printer.Text = "9";
                }
                else printer.Text = printer.Text + "9";
            }
        }

        private void clickedC(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printer.Text = "0";
        }
```

I expect that right after I cliked the "c" buttom , when the displayed test is zero, to the key's input to work normally.

Oh, and if someone could have an shorter alternative to this terrible Key Input code that I would be very pleased.

Comment: The "C" buttom's code are the last lines in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of j-a-k is correct.

I made you an alternative:

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0)
    {
        displayText("0");
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
    {
        displayText("1");
    }

    private void displayText(string digit)
    {
        if (printer.Text == "0")
            printer.Text = digit;
        else
            printer.Text += digit;
    }
```

There is no need for all the if elses, it makes the code hard to read. So I broke it into a list of seperate if statements.
I also created a private void here the repetitive code goes into so you can keep your code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Or you could throw it all away and do this:

```
displayText(e.KeyValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Cool, no problem. Can you accept this answer so it may help other people? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the focus is lost on the object where "numberKeyPressed" is hooked once you click the button.

This can be fixed in the following way:

```
    private void clickedC(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printer.Text = "0";
        printer.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, I didn’t even know that Focus was a thing.

Comment: the solution provided by @Hypenate is flawed as you already have focus in the TextBox, no key press event is required.